# FXML using variables in labels

Tags: user-interface, variables, javafx, fxml

I am currently trying to display a variable parts = 8 in my fxml scene.

This is in my java doc, it's used in my code and declared like this:

```
public static  int parts = 8;
```

In my controller I have tried to diplay it using this method:

```
@FXML
private static Label guess;

 @FXML
    private void DisplayNoGuesses(ActionEvent event) {
         guess.setText(Game.parts.toString());

    }
```

So that the user can see it in a label.

However I am now getting the error "int cannot be dereferenced"

Is this because I'm trying to convert the int to a string? 
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `guess.setText(String.valueOf(parts));`

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem!!